# vba excel error "by ref argument type mismatch" when passing key to function as string argument

Tags: vba, excel, argument-passing

I'm getting an "by ref argument type mismatch" error on the following sub test():

```
Public Function GetOtherDict(k As String, dict As Dictionary) As Dictionary

    Dim otherDict As New Dictionary

    curItem = dict.Item(k)
    otherDict.Add curItem, curItem

    Set GetOtherDict = otherDict
End Function

Public Sub Test()

    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    dict.Add "a", 1
    dict.Add "b", 2

    For Each k In dict.Keys

        Dim otherDict As Dictionary
        Dim curKey As String
        curKey = k 
        Set otherDict = GetOtherDict(k, dict)

    Next

End Sub
```

When I call the function `GetOtherDict` with the `curKey` argument instead of the `k` argument the error disappears.

Can you please tell me why do I need this redundant declaration?

Comment: What is `hub` and how have you declared it?

Comment: sorry, "hub" should be "k". I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you have declared `k As String` in the function so the function expects that you pass a `String` to it. Since you have not declared `k` in `Sub Test()`, `k` will be considered as a `Variant` and hence you are getting that "**by ref argument type mismatch**" Error.

It doesn't give you an error when you pass `curKey` because `curKey` is defined as `String` in `Sub Test()` which is what the function expects...

**Another TIP**: Please use `Option Explicit` at the end of the code.

Comment: Thanks. I just debugged and saw that a foreach itteration varaible must be variant or object. previously I thought that since it itterates dictionary keys, there will be some automatic string cast.

Comment: Does "Option Explicit On" forces me to declare all varibles with the Dim keyword?

Comment: Yes. When `Option Explicit` appears at the top of your code then you must explicitly declare all variables either by using the `Dim` or `ReDim` statements.

Answer (score -1):

I havent programmed vba for a long time but try

```
Public Function GetOtherDict(k As String, dict As Dictionary) As Dictionary

     Dim otherDict As New Dictionary

     curItem = dict.Item(hub)
     otherDict.Add curItem, curItem

     return otherDict
End Function
```